# Cuando se establece una conexion con la DB?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy aprendiendo un poco sobre JDBC y MySQL y me surgió una duda al momento de conectar con la base de datos, y es saber en que momento realmente se "abre" la conexión hacia la misma.

- Cuando se instancia el objeto Connection?.

  > Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(.......);
- Cuando se crea algun Statement con el objeto Connection?.

  > PreparedStatment ps = con.PrepareStatement(........);
- Cuando se ejecuta el PreparedStatment?.

  > ps.executeUpdate() o ps.executeQuery()?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tengo entendido la conexión se establece al crear el objeto **Connetion** mediante la llamada al método **DriverManager.getConnection(...);**

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
```

Te recomiendo leer la API de java aqui [Class DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) y [algo más](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefjdbc34565.html).

Answer (score 0):

seria cuando llamas al connector o driver que te permite conectarte a la base de datos aqui es donde se conecta a la base de datos.

Cuando se instancia el objeto Connection?. Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(.......);